# Login time issues on linux

Tags: linux, authentication, passwords

I have observed that it takes a very long time on a Linux machine to deny the user to log in in case he mistyped his password than it takes to log him in actually. The difference can be even 5 seconds. Why is this?

Comment: Security by delay. Every failed attempt introduces an enforced delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long standing habit to enforce a delay when a login fails. The rationale is that it rate-limits attacks.

There's a facility in the Pluggable Authentication Modules (PAM) of Linux which provides for a delay on a failed login attempt.

For PAM-Linux, the api is called [`pam_fail_delay`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_fail_delay), and is invoked in the authentication modules, and it requests a delay of the passed in number of microseconds. The system actually puts in an up to +/-25% delay in.